# Vue.js. Не работает одновременно роутинг и отображение значений

Tags: javascript, маршрутизация, vue.js

Я взял пример роутинга на vue.js и решил к нему добавить отображение параметров. Не могу разобраться, но работает только что-то одно по отдельности.
Вот пример.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/library/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/library/router.js"></script>

    <div id="app">
      <h1>Hello App! {{Myvalue1}}</h1> 
      <p>
        <!-- use v-link directive for navigation. -->
        <a v-link="{ path: '/foo' }">Go to Foo</a>
        <a v-link="{ path: '/bar' }">Go to Bar</a>
      </p>
      <!-- route outlet -->
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

<script>
var Foo = Vue.extend({
    template: '<p>This is foo!</p>'
})

var Bar = Vue.extend({
    template: '<p>This is bar!</p>'
})


var App = Vue.extend({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        Myvalue1: 'Roman'
    }})
var router = new VueRouter({
    history:true
}) 

router.map({
    '/foo': {
        component: Foo
    },
    '/bar': {
        component: Bar
    }
})

router.start(App, '#app')
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно изменить data,что б значение возвращала функция

```
var App = Vue.extend({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
       return {
          Myvalue1: 'Roman'
       }
     }
})
```